# Is it okay to link node modules files in webpack.config.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, dependency-management

In some projects, I saw developers didn't link to node_modules files in webpack.config.js (eg. "./node_modules/boostrap/dist/js/boostrap.bundle.js"), instead, they copied the file to assets/js and linked it there. Some of my friends also told me that they prefer this option because they never feel safe with linking to node_modules (I guess as somebody may use `npm update`...?)

What would you call a "good practice"? Is it totally fine to link to node_modules? If not - what wrong can happen?

I used this method in small projects as I don't think there is a need for doubling files but in larger - for peace of mind - I used the path to assets

Comment: `npm update` won't change anything if you pin dependencies (which you really should)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be okay to do it. Purely from the build step perspective, it doesn't make a difference.

The trade offs you are making between using the node modules as npm provides them (node_modules) and storing your own copies, in an `assets` or `vendors` folder, are about:

1. security
2. source code management & development efficiency
3. storage space

When all the thousands of developers around the world create little pet projects and push them to Github, it wouldn't make sense for all of them to store their own copy of JQuery and then push it into their Github repo. Instead we push a package.json file that lists it as a dependency, we do this for every third party dependency and prevent creating a repository where a lot (even most) of the code is not application code, but dependencies. That is good.

On the other hand, if a developer always downloads dependencies every time a new project is started/cloned/forked, you potentially risk, with every module download, the chance of installing a compromised package version. For this we solve with vulnerability scanners, semantic versioning and lock files (`package-lock.json`) to give you control on how and when you get updates.

Another problem with downloading always is the bandwidth it consumes. For this we solve with a local cache. So, even if you uninstall a module from one project, npm doesn't really delete it from your drive. It keeps a copy on a cache folder. This works really well for most developers, but not so much in an enterprise environment with massive applications.

A problem, that has impacted already the world severely, is that if a module author decides to delete the code then lots of apps stop working because they can't find the dependency anymore. See [left-pad broke Node, Babel...](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/) (It also broke things at my work)

The issue with moving things out from `node_modules` to `assets` is that if your app has 100 dependencies, your are not going to want to do that 100 times. You might as well save in your source control system the complete source code found in `node_modules`. That comes at a price of course, that folder can have a huge size.

A good balance can be found by using different tools and approaches. Wether you vendorize third party dependencies (store your own copy) or not depends on what has the better cost/risk ratio in your situation.